# How to open MFC dialog from WPF application?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mfc, pinvoke, showdialog

I have created dialog in .dll project. Now I want to open that dialog from WPF application by clicking on button. Following is the code for dialog:

TestDialog.h:

```
class CTestDialog : public CDialogEx
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CTestDialog)

public:
    CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~CTestDialog();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = 1000 };

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

TestDialog.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MFCDll.h"
#include "TestDialog.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CTestDialog, CDialogEx)

CTestDialog::CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CTestDialog::IDD, pParent)
{
}

CTestDialog::~CTestDialog()
{
}

void CTestDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTestDialog, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

I have created export function which create object of dialog and open that dialog by calling the DoModel() function.

```
extern "C" void PASCAL EXPORT ShowDialogFromDLL()
{
    CTestDialog dlg;
    theApp.m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
    dlg.DoModal();
}
```

After that I am calling this export function from WPF form following is the code for WPF Form.

MainWindow.xaml.vb:

```
namespace MainApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("MFCDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
        public static extern void ShowDialogFromDLL();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ShowDialogFromDLL();
        }
    }
}
```

But now when I call ShowDialogFromDLL(); after clicking button.It will throw me exception as

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: E:\EDR1\Test\MainApp\bin\Debug\MainApp.vshost.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\include\afxwin1.inl
Line: 24

For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

Above error is coming when I call `dlg.DoModal();` method.

Answer (score 2):

**This should work** -

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall ShowDialogFromDLL()
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState())
    CTestDialog dlg;
    dlg.DoModal();
}
```

When building a regular DLL that dynamically links to MFC, you need to use the macro [AFX_MANAGE_STATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30c674tx%28VS.80%29.aspx) to switch the MFC module state correctly.